# Making mockito to use the real Log4j during unit testing

Tags: mockito, log4j, junit5

During the unit testing of method *Utility#sum*, I want that the *log* should print the *sum* on the console.

```java
public class Utility {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Utility.class);
   
    private Utility() {
    }

    public static Integer getSum(Integer a, Integer b) {
        Integer sum = a + b
        log.info(sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

For that in my test *testGetSumRealLogger* I am passing a real *Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())*, but in method *Utility#sum* its is initialized to null.

In my second test *testGetSumMockedLogger* I am passing a mocked  *Logger log = Mockito.mock(Logger.class)*, this time the log inside method Utility#sum is not null, but does not print anything.

```java
class UtilityTest {

    @Test
    void testGetSumRealLogger() throws Exception {
        try (MockedStatic<Logger> mockedStaticLoggerBean = Mockito.mockStatic(Logger.class)) {

            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
            mockedStaticLoggerBean.when(() -> Logger.getLogger(Utility.class)).thenReturn(log);

            assertEquals(4, Utility.getSum(2, 2));
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testGetSumMockedLogger() throws Exception {
        try (MockedStatic<Logger> mockedStaticLoggerBean = Mockito.mockStatic(Logger.class)) {

            Logger log = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
            mockedStaticLoggerBean.when(() -> Logger.getLogger(Utility.class)).thenReturn(log);

            assertEquals(4, Utility.getSum(2, 2));
        }
    }

}
```

How can I get the Logger to print something in the Utility#sum method without refactoring the code.
I am using Junit 5 with mockito-inline, 3.11.2.
I also have a proper log4j.xml in the test resources.
Please avoid suggesting logging is bad during the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, no mocking is necessary in your case: the real implementation of Logger.getLogger does the right thing.

Thus, the code like:

```java
@Test
public void testGetSum() {
    assertEquals(4, Utility.getSum(2, 2));
}
```

works fine and obeys the settings of the log4j configuration.

Both your attempts of providing logger via mocking static `getLogger` break this functionality.

**Attempt 1: providing real logger**

```java
try (MockedStatic<Logger> mockedStaticLoggerBean = Mockito.mockStatic(Logger.class)) {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    mockedStaticLoggerBean.when(() -> Logger.getLogger(Utility.class)).thenReturn(log);

    assertEquals(4, Utility.getSum(2, 2));
}
```

This is broken because you initialize the `log` variable when static methods of the Logger class are already patched. As no implementation for getLogger has been provided by you, it returns the default value for any reference type - null.

**Attempt 2: providing mock logger**

```java
try (MockedStatic<Logger> mockedStaticLoggerBean = Mockito.mockStatic(Logger.class)) {

    Logger log = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
    mockedStaticLoggerBean.when(() -> Logger.getLogger(Utility.class)).thenReturn(log);

    assertEquals(4, Utility.getSum(2, 2));
}
```

This is broken because the mock `log` you provide does not have any behaviour specified - it does nothing when it is interacted with.